# grant access to devops repo only without access to project?

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, devops

In Azure devops is it possible to grant access (read-only) to a repo in a project without the user having access to the project containing the repo?
We want to use the repo basically as a file share with clients that shouldn't be able to see all our code/scripts/pipelines etc that exist in the parent project and other repos.

As stakeholder access on the project and Reader rights on the repo they had too much access to the project. Removing them from the project and creating a new group with limited repo rights they got to a forbidden, access denied screen which makes me think they have to have access to the project.

My testing is limited because of corporate environment I am unable to create additional users/emails and don't want to have to keep asking co-workers to test every change I could try.

Comment: Git itself has no access control, so this is purely an azure-devops issue (to which I don't know the answer, but there's no need to ask more generally).

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps is designed to enable all valid users to view all objects defined in the system. You can restrict access to specific resources by setting the permission state to **Deny**.

So not quite sure if this specific requirement is achievable. The closest you could probably get to is this: [Assign read-only rights to a single repository in Azure DevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-setting-up-repository-permissions/).

Here is a very similar idea on Developer Community from 2019: [Restrict access to dev ops functionality for a guest user](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Restrict-access-to-dev-ops-functionality/680403). One more resolved post: [Restrict access to specific objects in DevOps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Restrict-access-to-specific-objects-in-D/1071155).

If you think this implementing this suggestion can benefit others in the Community as well, do request it as a new feature on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) for Azure DevOps.

Also go through the [elaborate documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/?view=azure-devops) available for configuring ADO granular security controls and check if [changing individual permission at the project-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-individual-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#change-individual-permission-at-the-project-level) helps.